# Upgrade react from 0.14 to the current version

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to upgrade my react project from 0.14, as of now there are dependencies that are deprecated and there is lot change in the code that should be made. I came to know the ways are to upgrade the react step by step based on the releases or create a new react app with current versions and get the dependencies required for my existing project.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0-beta4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.13.0",
    "bower-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.9",
    "chai": "^3.2.0",
    "copyfiles": "^0.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "eslint": "^1.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.3.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "glob": "^6.0.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "isparta-instrumenter-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "postcss": "^5.0.11",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.9",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.3",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "babel-es6-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.0.0",
    "deep-diff": "^0.3.3",
    "export-to-csv": "^0.2.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "jed": "1.1.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "jquery-bbq": "0.0.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "material-ui": "^0.14.4",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.3",
    "normalize.css": "^3.0.3",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.2",
    "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.0.22",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^2.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0",
    "react-dropdown": "^0.7.2",
    "react-fa": "^4.0.0",
    "react-ga4": "^2.1.0",
    "react-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "react-pager": "1.1.x",
    "react-router": "^2.2.2",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^1.8.0",
    "stripe": "^4.4.0"
  }
```

This is my configuration file:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const { HotModuleReplacementPlugin } = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const port = 7000;
const srcPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../src');
const publicPath = '/assets/';

module.exports = {
  // port: port,
  // debug: true,
  output: {
    publicPath: publicPath
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: false,
    port: port,
    publicPath: publicPath,
    noInfo: false,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    alias: {
      actions: path.join(srcPath, 'actions'),
      components: path.join(srcPath, 'components'),
      sources: path.join(srcPath, 'sources'),
      stores: path.join(srcPath, 'stores'),
      styles: path.join(srcPath, 'styles'),
      config: path.join(srcPath, 'config', process.env.REACT_WEBPACK_ENV)
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: srcPath,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader', // Use babel-loader for JavaScript files
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'] // Babel presets for ES6 and React
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'json-loader'}]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', {loader: 'sass-loader', options:{ outputStyle: 'expanded', indentedSyntax: true}}] // Updated sass loader
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'less-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'stylus-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            minetype: 'application/font-woff'
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  // postcss: function () {
  //   return [];
  // },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'main.css',
    }),
    new HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

[image for one of my enivorment configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvufy.png)

attached is my package.json file, suggest me how to proceed, if anyone has the live experience  or knowledge in doing that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/CHANGELOG.md) yourself before you get into trouble.

Answer (score 2):

That React version seems a little bit too old!

Anyways, I recently migrated a big corporate web application from React 16 to 18, and I had to restart a few times because of the complexity the migration started to get at some point of the task

However, I stumbled upon a good and effective approach:

- Created a new react app using the [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/) scripts (use the correct version based on the react version you want your app to have)
- Started copying (starting from the homepage) file by file into the new application and while doing that
- Each time I copied a file I'd comment out all the external dependent react components (if they had a tree of custom react child components again) and added all the dependencies that file needed to work
- If any issue arose from that specific file because of some deprecation, fix it and note it down since you might need it again for future files

Once you copied all your files your application should be all updated. Try to push back any webpack particular feature that create-react-app scripts do not offer to eject as late as possible them

Comment: I have started doing the same but as you mentioned I'm getting trouble in the 1st page itself because of web-pack as couldn't able to find something in the Server.js file

``require('core-js/fn/object/assign');``

Comment: Server.js seems like you are having a frontend + proxy server with express situation. That seems like an important piece of information to have :D Anyways they should be separated, and if they are already not, at that point you have your express server up and running separately, and then you can start with the React part connecting it (possible guide: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/)

Comment: I tried to modify and look for this and I'm still getting the same error in my config file 

`ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[7] should be one of these:
   ["..." | false | 0 | "" | null | undefined | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, `
I've added config in the question

Comment: create-react-app scripts hide the webpack configuration files, so you shouldn't need to create a webpack configuration file. Most of the functionalities are available through some autoconfiguration. Is there any particular reason you want to configure a custom webpack file? If you REALLY feel like you need to then you can run `eject` and it will remove all the create-react-app scripts configurations, but it's non reversibl

Comment: we've like multiple environments so we use a diff config file. will the new create-react-app script will handle this situation? I have added the screenshot of one of my env in the question and other environments also look mostly the same

Comment: It looks like the main configuration there is the hot reaload that is hanlded automatically that create-react-app. But if you have any environment specific variables to then use in your code you an use https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables